# Excel formula needs to grab one part of cell data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a formula that is working.. some of the time. I tried searching and figure out what tweaks I need with no luck.
I am exporting emails from out look with a macro. I am breaking up the body into cells as it comes out as one long string. 
The problem I am having is that I need the first cell of my results to find a certain field, then give me EVERY thing before the field no matter how long. The formula below worked for one email, but not for others. Also the 260 limit cut of part of the content.

=TRIM(REPLACE(LEFT(TRIM(CLEAN(B4)),FIND(IF(COUNTIF(B4,"*Response Summary:*"),"Response Summary:","Response Summary:"),TRIM(CLEAN(B4)))-1),1,FIND("Response Summary:",TRIM(CLEAN(B4)))-262,""))

Answer (score 0):

I admit I don't understand your question (but suspect it's not just me or you would have had an answer by now!) However, maybe:

> =TRIM(LEFT(CLEAN(B4),FIND(B3,B4)-1))

would help, where `B3` contains `Response Summary:` which I assume is the "certain field".

I am not even clear why the tags (Excel) when the macro is *ex*porting from Outlook?